# Opensearch datetime sql plugin query

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I created the "demo_table" index in opensearch using a data query language.

```
PUT /demo_table
{
  "mappings" : {
    "properties" : {
      "driver_id" : {
        "type" : "long"},
      "to_time_stamp" : {
        "type" : "date",
        "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After insertion of rows using CSV file having two columns same named as 'driver_id' and 'to_time_stamp'. I received data using the query as:

`POST demo_table/_search`

Result/Output:

```
{
  "took" : 6,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 13,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "demo_table",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Qk69ZoEBJ9QiQQN5w0W5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "driver_id" : "12345",
          "to_time_stamp" : "2022-02-01 03:00:00.000"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "demo_table",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "RU69ZoEBJ9QiQQN5w0W5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "driver_id" : "123456",
          "to_time_stamp" : "2022-02-01 14:30:00.000"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "demo_table",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Rk69ZoEBJ9QiQQN5w0W5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "driver_id" : "123457",
          "to_time_stamp" : "2022-02-01 15:00:00.000"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "demo_table",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "PE69ZoEBJ9QiQQN5w0W5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "driver_id" : "123452",
          "to_time_stamp" : "2022-02-01 00:00:00.000"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "demo_table",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "P069ZoEBJ9QiQQN5w0W5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "driver_id" : "123451",
          "to_time_stamp" : "2022-02-01 01:30:00.000"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "demo_table",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Q069ZoEBJ9QiQQN5w0W5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "driver_id" : "123450",
          "to_time_stamp" : "2022-02-01 13:30:00.000"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "demo_table",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Pk69ZoEBJ9QiQQN5w0W5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "driver_id" : "312345",
          "to_time_stamp" : "2022-02-01 01:00:00.432"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "demo_table",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "QE69ZoEBJ9QiQQN5w0W5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "driver_id" : "102345",
          "to_time_stamp" : "2022-02-01 02:00:00.000"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "demo_table",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "SE69ZoEBJ9QiQQN5w0W5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "driver_id" : "123454",
          "to_time_stamp" : "2022-02-01 16:00:00.000"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "demo_table",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "PU69ZoEBJ9QiQQN5w0W5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "driver_id" : "123455",
          "to_time_stamp" : "2022-02-01 00:30:00.123"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

but when I do the same simple thing using SQL plugin query I get the error.

```
POST /_plugins/_sql
{
  "query":"select * from demo_table"
}
```

I took help from the [functions](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/search-plugins/sql/functions#date-and-time) and [data types](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/search-plugins/sql/datatypes/) opensearch documentation pages and tried few things like type casting after storing DateTime as the string. I want to run a few queries involving comparison over DateTime like

```
POST /_plugins/_sql
{ "query":"select * from demo_table where cast(to_time_stamp as timestamp) < cast('2022-02-01 02:30:00' as timestamp)" 
}
```

```
POST /_plugins/_sql
{ "query":"select * from demo_table where to_time_stamp = '2022-02-01 03:00:00.000';"
}
```

Note: These queries can be wrongly formatted but just an example to give an idea. I want to run the maximum possible SQL queries over created indices.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks